# Pentaho Kettle for Flow-Based Programming

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, dataflow, noflo

Is Pentaho Data Integration aka Kettle suitable for Flow-Based Programming FBP?

Kettle is an ETL(Extraction, Transformation and Loading) Tool and is based on [FBP concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming)

There is [User Defined Java Class step](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/10/the-user-defined-java-class-step/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20AdventuresWithOpenSourceBi%20%28Adventures%20with%20Open%20Source%20BI%29) and has a [SDK](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/The+PDI+SDK) so you can extend Kettle and you can integrate [Kettle with Java Web Apps](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/blog/kettle/pentaho-kettle-within-a-web-application/).

Is possible to build a web application using only Kettle with custom plugin?

Worth it write a custom plugin for web apps?

Which are the missing steps in Kettle for web development?

I should go for [noflojs](http://noflojs.org/) and leave Java?

[JavaFBP](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/jsyntax.htm) is a java implementation of FBP. I can use JavaFBP to build a component that for example reads an Excel file. But this component already exist in Kettle!

My purpose is do some research and build a prototype not a real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say so yes. Kettle is being used in a lot of use cases these days which are not typical ETL.

Examples:

1. At the recent PCM event in Lisbon we saw the use of PDI to manage "builds" and deployments of solutions.
2. Sparkl - This is a biggie. Sparkl is a plugin builder framework for Pentaho which lets you use CDE to build the UI and Kettle to do the server based work.  It's very clever and I recommend looking out for the video from the Pentaho Community Meetup.  When you've built your app it can be zipped up as a pentaho platform plugin and distributed on the Marketplace.
3. Streaming - There are various cases now of kettle behaving more like an ESB where you have an endless transformation or job processing data as it arrives.

Also Kettle 5 has a whole bunch of new plugin technology, and "extension points" so kettle is starting to become a platform in itself, in which you can do any manner of data related activities!

Comment: Thanks, That is what I was looking for, someone that tell me that I'm not crazy.